# troubles running my app directly in a iDevice

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-provisioning

i am kinda new with objective c and I starting to develop iOS apps, i want to try my app on my ipad, i have an apple account, in the code signing part i use my code signing identity and in the provisional profile i put the provisional profile of my team, in the past that was enough, now i am getting an error, "Shell Script invocation Error"

/Users/MyUser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyAppName-diujlbcwyooylxalicyiojbktolk/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/MyAppName/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/MyAppName.build/Release-iphoneos/MyAppName.build/Script-50524F424C454D533F.sh: line 4: /Library/JailCoder/Entitlements/Entitlements.py: No such file or directory

do you have any idea what is going on? or how can i fix this issue will be very appreciated
thanks in Advance

Comment: You used Jailcoder to run your app on the device. Is that correct?

Comment: thats the odd part, i am not using that! and even installed but the app that im  trying to run was build with another computer wich maybe was with jailcoder.

Comment: Can you upload the project so that I can have a look at it?